# For a given $M$, how can we solve $M=w\vec 1 ^T + \vec 1v^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matrix-equations, outer-product

Let a matrix $M\in\mathbb R^{m\times n}$ be given. Define $\vec 1 = [1, \ldots ,1]^T$ to be a vector of all ones (I don't specify its length since it will be clear from the context.)

Under what conditions on $M$ can we find $v\in\mathbb R^n$ and $w\in\mathbb R^m$ such that $(\ref{e})$ holds?

$$
M=w\vec 1 ^T + \vec 1v^T \label{e}\tag{1}
$$

Under what conditions on $M$ will such $v$ and $w$ be unique?

My attempt: I tried assuming that some $x \in \text{ker}(w^T)$, then we'd have $$x^T M = x^T \vec 1 v^T$$ which doesn't seem to bring us any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write $u$ instead of $1$. So you want 
$$
M = wu^t + u v^t
$$
Well, let $s_i = e_1 - e_i$. Then $u^t s_i = 0$. So 
$$
\begin{align}
Ms_i 
&= wu^ts_i + u v^t s_i\\
&= u v^t s_i
\end{align}
$$
Since $Ms_i$ is just the $i$th column of $M$ minus the first column of $M$, the left side's easy to understand.

On the right, $v^t s_i$ is just $q = v_i - v_1$. You multiply that by $u$ and you get a column of $q$s.

In short:

If there's a solution, then the difference between the $i$th column of $M$  and the first column should be a column of constants. (Same thing applies to rows).

Now you've got all the differences $v_i - v_1$ and $w_i - w_1$; how can you find the actual $v$ and $w$ vectors (if they exist)? That's a little messy. Once you know $v_1$, everything else is simple, for $v_2$ is just $(v_2 - v_1)$, which you've computed, added to $v_1$; the same goes for all the other entries of $v$. And $m_{11} = v_1 + w_1$, so you can find $w_1 = v_1 - m_11$.

The problem is that if $v = au$ and $w = bu$, then $v' = (a+b)u, w' = 0$ is another solution to the problem, i.e., in certain cases, there may not be a single solution, but rather infinitely many solutions.

Wait...in general, you can add $au$ to $v$ and subtract $au$ from $w$ to get a new solution! So if there's a solution, there are infinitely many solutions. And one of them has $v_1 = 0$.

So here goes, in simple form:

If all column-differences and all row-differences are constant vectors, there's a solution. If not, there isn't.

In the first case, you can compute a solution $v, w$ as follows:

$$
v_1 = 0\\
v_2 = m_{12}\\
\ldots \\
v_n = m_{1,n}
$$
That gets you $v$. Now
$$
w_1 = m_{11}\\
w_2 = m_{21}-m_{11}\\
\ldots
w_n = m_{n,1} - m_{11}
$$
And I think that's it!